# Where is Kurisu Makise really is?

Tags: steins-gate

Suzuha was came from year 2036 and she said.

> "Okabe-san and Kurisu-san was death at that time (year 2036)"

here at alpha-time

But then i realize that in beginning episode and some episode, Kurisu-san was died because Okabe-san was pretend or her father either stab her in alpha-time.

Both alpha and beta world line tell that Kurisu Makise died at same case.
So, how Suzuha-san said that Kurisu-san in year 2036 still alive? Did i missed something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ok, there will be spoilers for Steins Gate 0 so be sure to watch that before reading this post or just read the overall part.**

In Beta timeline Kurisu is dead. The Beta timeline is the timeline we start to watch. Okabe goes to the Alpha timeline where Kurisu still lives. The Alpha timeline is where Mayuri destined to die. This is also the timeline we see the most in OG Steins Gate. All the experiment on D-Mail, stuff like changing the gender of Ruka, done in this timeline and get reverted by Okabe in order to save Mayuri.

In the end, Okabe understands that there is no way to keep Mayuri alive in the Alpha timeline. He goes back to the Beta timeline in order to save Kurisu. He fails once and this is the start of Steins Gate 0. In S;G0 Okabe chooses to stay in this timeline and keep Mayuri save by sacrificing Kurisu so Kurisu is still dead in this timeline. We also saw a small segment in the middle of S;G0 where another version of Okabe chose Kurisu over Mayuri. That is the Alpha line.

**So overall:**

- The alpha timeline is where Kurisu lives and Mayuri dies.
- The beta timeline is where Kurisu dies and Mayuri lives.

Because of two distinct timelines, there are actually two different versions of Suzuha.

Comment: if i'm not wrong in Steins;Gate: Load Region of Déjà Vu. Suzuha was said there's "R"-timeline. Where Mayuri and Kurisu are both alive, but Okabe was disappeared. Is that true?

Comment: Yes the R timeline is very very similar to Steins Gate timeline but due to Reading Steiner, Okabe vanishes in Steins Gate timeline thus creating R timeline.

Comment: @GilangRizqi Note that *Steins;Gate: Load Region of Déjà Vu* is often considered non-canon by fans because it breaks the fundamental "no parallel dimensions" rule that's established in *Steins;Gate*.